# can't install katalon on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qapplication, katalon

I'm trying to install katalon studio on ubunut. But it keeps giving me the following error:

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre

sudo update-alternatives --config java //then choose the openjdk-8-jre option

I followed the following steps, but with no success.

Comment: What _is_ the error? What does your terminal _say_ after you run the commands? All you've given us are [commands for setting up the environment](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/set-up-katalon-studio/installation/katalon-studio-for-linux-gui#environment-requirements). They are not error messages.

Comment: I found this useful to your query - [LINK](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/set-up-katalon-studio/installation/katalon-studio-for-linux-gui)

Answer (score 1):

you need OpenJDK 8 on your Ubuntu to run katalon

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -> is command to install OpenJDK 8 (requirement to run katalon studio)

Verify the version of the JDK again using  java -version in terminal.

to activate katalon you need the following step:

1. go to extraction folder of your The Katalon Studio and lauch the app
   [image]